# IdentityServer: Check if scopes present in a policy for authentication in OpenId Connect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver3

There are 2 projects:

```
1. IdentityServer project
2. Client Project
```

In my Client Project, I have a controller with policy based authentication:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Authorize(Policy ="SomePolicy")]
public class BankController : ControllerBase
{
...    
}
```

On the Startup.cs of the Client Project I have added the Policy authentication code which says the token should contain "scope" having value "fullaccess". See below code:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("SomePolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "fullaccess");
    });
});
```

The "fullaccess" are ApiScopes defined on appsetting.json on the IdentityServer project.

```
"IdentityServerSettings": {
  "ApiScopes": [
    {
      "Name": "fullaccess"
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

**The code is working well on postman testing.**

Now I added this scope on OIDC on my Client Project by adding the line `options.Scope.Add("fullaccess");`, see below code.

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
     options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
     options.ClientId = "postman";
     options.ResponseType = "code";
     
     //adding fullaccess scope
     options.Scope.Add("fullaccess");

     options.SaveTokens = true;
 });
```

Now I try to enter BankController on the browser. This controller is protected by this policy which I have created. The following things happens:

1. I am redirected to IdentityServer login page.
2. I then login, after this IdentityServer redirects me back to BankController.
3. Now instead of Bank Controller showing the content. I am redirected to **AccessDenied** because "fullaccess" scope seems to be absent, but why?

The console shows the following error:

```
Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement:Claim.Type=scope and Claim.Value is one of the following values: (fullaccess)
```

How can it be solved?

Comment: Is there any error messages in console or browser?

Comment: @TinyWang no errors.

Comment: Hi,@yogihosting, pls allow me to post my programming steps below as we can't find the error. Hoping it can help you to integrate identity server4 : )

Comment: Is there any progress? Any further issue or it's useless at all?

Comment: @TinyWang no progress. I have added a few more things on the question (and error on console). Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can share my integration steps here to help you troubleshot.

Click here to see a [related blog](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4).

First, I created a asp.net core 3.1 mvc project, and installed these packages:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="4.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="3.1.17" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And then add a file named Config.cs, pls note here in my project the default port is 5001 for https, see launchSetting.json:

```
using IdentityModel;
using IdentityServer4;
using IdentityServer4.Models;
using IdentityServer4.Test;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResource
                {
                    Name = "role",
                    UserClaims = new List<string> {"role"}
                }
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetApiScopes()
        {
            return new List<ApiScope>
            {
                new ApiScope("api1.read", "Read Access to API #1"),
                new ApiScope("api1.write", "Write Access to API #1")
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
        {
            return new List<ApiResource> {
                new ApiResource
                {
                    Name = "api1",
                    DisplayName = "API #1",
                    Description = "Allow the application to access API #1 on your behalf",
                    Scopes = new List<string> {"api1.read", "api1.write"},
                    ApiSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("ScopeSecret".Sha256())},
                    UserClaims = new List<string> {"role"}
                }
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
            {
                // other clients omitted...

                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "oidcClient",
                    ClientName = "Example Client Application",
                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("SuperSecretPassword".Sha256())}, // change me!
    
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RedirectUris = new List<string> {"https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc"},
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        "role",
                        "api1.read"
                    },

                    RequirePkce = true,
                    AllowPlainTextPkce = false
                },
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "oauthClient",
                    ClientName = "Example client application using client credentials",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("SuperSecretPassword".Sha256())}, // change me!
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string> {"api1.read"}
                }
            };
        }

        public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
        {
            return new List<TestUser>
            {
                new TestUser {
                    SubjectId = "5BE86359-073C-434B-AD2D-A3932222DABE",
                    Username = "tiny",
                    Password = "111",
                    Claims = new List<Claim> {
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "tiny@gmail.com"),
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "admin")
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Next, we can use powershell to run a command to install default [identity server 4 ui](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI#quickstart-ui-for-identityserver4) in our project for the login part. Because it will also provide a HomeController.cs, we can rename or delete the original HomeController when creating the project. Go to the root directory of the project, open powershell and run:

```
iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/main/getmain.ps1'))
```

Then we need to modify the startup.cs, here's my file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.GetApiScopes())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            //If we only need to enable the token validation for api, use the code commented below
            //services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            //.AddIdentityServerAuthentication("Bearer", options =>
            //{
            //    options.ApiName = "api1";
            //    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
            //});

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("cookie")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                options.ClientId = "oidcClient";
                options.ClientSecret = "SuperSecretPassword";

                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.UsePkce = true;
                options.ResponseMode = "query";

                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc"; // default redirect URI

                // options.Scope.Add("oidc"); // default scope
                // options.Scope.Add("profile"); // default scope
                options.Scope.Add("api1.read");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, let's comment the attribute `[AllowAnonymous]` in HomeController and add an action for privacy page:

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Privacy() => View();
```

we can also add a new controller to made it work like an api and add `[Authorize]` on that controller,e.g.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HelloController : Controller
    {
        public string Index()
        {
            return "hello world";
        }
    }
}
```

Then start the program, we can see home page directly, but if we visit `https://localhost:5001/hello/index` , `https://localhost:5001/home/privacy`,it will redirect to a sign in page, after sign in(user name and password is defined in config.cs) we can see privary page or response message.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: no, my authorize attribute is [Authorize(Policy ="SomePolicy")] and not [Authorize]